# INPUT 100-240VAC - will it only work with Voltage Rating within 100-240 ?

Tags: voltage

Written on my Smartphone Charger is: INPUT 100-240VAC. Does that mean it will only work with Voltage Rating within 100-240, not higher than 240, and lower than 100 ?

Comment: There are 10 % design margin on top of that but nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: Yes... Or, Device will perform as expected within that range... Otherwise no guarantee!

Answer (score 1):

This means that the manufacturer "guarantees" that the product can work with input voltages between 100 and 240Vac. Of course there are some tolerances, but this range is "guaranteed".

You know, since those type of chargers are off-line flyback switching regulators, lower input voltage increases input current and higher input voltage increases spikes. So the product should not be damaged under these conditions. Besides, I'm sure that these type of products are tested with extreme voltage levels *(Let's assume that 85-265Vac for 1 hr @ 50°C)*. So yes, they can work either with >240V or <100V, but within some (say, %10) tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

The charger is most probably a pcm flyback charger. Such systems have a minimum and maximum duty cycle determined during design. The minimum duty cycle determines the upper voltage limit and the maximum duty cycle determines the lower voltage limit.

Since the upper voltage limit is determined corresponding input capacitors are selected.

A to high input voltage brings the duty cycle below the minimum range with unstable operation and possible destruction of the circuits as a result. Apart from that the input capacitors can get destroyed.

A to low input voltage bring the duty cycle above the maximum range resulting in unstable operation and possible circuit destruction as a result.

Answer (score 0):

AIUI the range printed on the label is a range of "nominal" voltages. IIRC manufacturers are supposed to support 10% either side of the nominal voltage range to allow for supply variability. So a nominal 100-240V input should actually accept anywhere from 90V to 264V.

Assuming this is a switched mode power supply there will likely be an undervoltage cutout to protect against excessive current draw in the event of brownouts. Exactly what point that will cut-in at is likely device specific. Signficiant overvoltage is very likely to damage the power supply.